# display different suffix for each array element in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$all_categories=get_cats($cat);
$headingPrinted = false;
$childCount = 0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++)
{    

 $arr=get_gender($cat);

 if($arr[$i]=='0')

 {
    if (!$headingPrinted) {
     echo "&nbsp&nbsp"."Sons:";
      $headingPrinted = true;
    }  
 echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i].",";
 $childCount++;
 }



 } 
     if ($childCount >= 3) {
echo $childCount,  $childCount == 1 ;  
} 
else {
// you may want to do something if none found
}
$headingPrinted = false;
$childCount = 0;

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++)
{    

 $arr=get_gender($cat);



if($arr[$i]=='1'){
if (!$headingPrinted) {
     echo "&nbsp&nbsp"."Daughters:";
      $headingPrinted = true;
    }  
echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i].",";
$childCount++;
  }

  } 
 if ($childCount >= 3) {
 echo $childCount,  $childCount == 1 ;  
 } 
 else {
// you may want to do something if none found
 }
```

I am displaying the word "Sons" then their names then their count and the word  "daughters"
then their names then count. I want to display like this
   Sons: a,b,c,d:4;
 Daughters:p,q,r,s:4;
$all_categories is an array in which i m getting all child of given id and get_gender and get_cats are functions.

now i m displaying **a,b,c,d, :4;**. I just want to remove that **comma** after last element of **array**..
I want to display count only if count of sons is greater than 2 and same for daughters.
If boys count  is 1 then the word "Sons:"a; and same for daughters.
if boys count is 2 then the word "Sons:" a,b; and same for daughters.
if boys count is greater than 2 then the word "Sons:" a,b,c:3; and same for daughters.
I want to display result same like above I said. So can anyone tried this???

Comment: could you show your database table structure? or model?

Comment: i have done all my code in view file and i have 2 table person and marriage. in person fname,father_id,person_id,gender,contact etc, and in marriage table husband_id (person_id in person table),wife_id(person_id in person table),marriage_id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Remove the last comma on last of displaying the Sons and daughters, check if next record exist then append the comma, else escape the comma.

```
$all_categories=get_cats($cat);
$headingPrinted = false;
$childCount = 0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++)
{    

 $arr=get_gender($cat);

 if($arr[$i]=='0')

 {
    if (!$headingPrinted) {
     echo "&nbsp&nbsp"."Sons:";
      $headingPrinted = true;
    }  
 echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i];


if(isset($all_categories[$i+1])){
      echo ",";

   }
 $childCount++;
 }



 } 
     if ($childCount >= 3) {
echo $childCount,  $childCount == 1 ;  
} 
else {
// you may want to do something if none found
}
$headingPrinted = false;
$childCount = 0;

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++)
{    

 $arr=get_gender($cat);



if($arr[$i]=='1'){
if (!$headingPrinted) {
     echo "&nbsp&nbsp"."Daughters:";
      $headingPrinted = true;
    }  
echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i];
if(isset($all_categories[$i+1])){
  echo ",";



}
    $childCount++;
      }

  } 
 if ($childCount >= 3) {
 echo $childCount,  $childCount == 1 ;  
 } 
 else {
// you may want to do something if none found
 }
```

Comment: In else part i should echo ;

Comment: it depends upon your logic. :)

Comment: I want to Display count only if son count is greater than 2 and same for daughters. I want exactly the same result like                     this first condition if son and daughter count less than 2     Sons:a,b; Daughters:p,q;                                                            second condition if son and daughter count greater than 2   Sons:a,b,c:3;    Daughters:p,q,r:3;