# separate the elements with comma and in the last element it is displaying comma so how to avoid comma in the end?

Tags: php

I am trying the following code to print the values with comma separated. i am getting "," after fetching the values.

```
<?php
   for($groups as $group)  // $groups is getting a,b,c,d values from datababse
   {
     echo $group['name'].',';
   }
 ?>
```

Consider that it having values as "a,b,c,d," here in the end , is printing
so how to avoid it.

Comment: use echo implode(",",$groups);

Comment: Please refer to the following link..it may help you..
[display different suffix][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321449/display-different-suffix-for-each-array-element-in-codeigniter-php

Answer (score 0):

do this instead:

`echo implode(',',$groups)`

Comment: Thank you. Used that but then also it displaying "," in the end.

Comment: Remove the `for` loop. Just use this alone.

Comment: okay. thanks. what if there are multiple values in the $groups?. consider $groups is returning name,id,address. then in that i want to display name only from $groups array.

Comment: Are the `name`,`id`,`address` array?

Comment: If `name`/`id`/`address` is an array as well, you can do `implode(',',$groups['name'])`

Answer (score 0):

A simple if condition that checks whether a $group element is the last in the $groups array should do the trick. Within the if, just print out that element without the comma.

Seeing as how it's usually more educationally  beneficial if you investigate on your own, I'm gonna let you figure out the code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To Remove the last comma on last of displaying array values, check if next record exist then append the comma, else escape the comma. I have provided the link..It definitely helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a disturbing lack of functioning answers so far:

```
echo join(', ', array_map(function ($group) { return $group['name']; }, $groups));
```

Or the same in PHP >= 5.5.:

```
echo join(', ', array_column($groups, 'name'));
```

Or the same in long-hand:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $names[] = $group['name'];
}
echo join(', ', $names);
```